# How to refresh all relations of a newly created model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, eloquent-relationship

I have two models with a 1:1 relationship named *User* and *UserProfile* respectively.

```php
class User extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['profile'];

    public function profile(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $touches = ['user'];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

After I create new records with these models and associate them, I should call the `refresh()` method (according to [Laravel's Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)) in order to reload the model and all of it's relations. But somehow this doesn't work.

```php
$user = new User($userData);
$profile = new UserProfile($profileData);

$user->save();

$user->profile()->save($profile);

$user->refresh();

$user->relationLoaded('profile'); // <-- This will be false

// $user = User::find($user->id); // <-- This will work
// $user->load('profile');        // <-- This will work

return response()->json(['data' => $user], 201);
```

Because the profile relation is not loaded, it will not be serialized and therefore it won't appear in JSON response.

I want to know if I'm doing anything wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, it is the expected behaviour. If you check your code, you are never loading the `profile` relationship in your `$user` object so it explains why:

```
$user->relationLoaded('profile'); // false
```

If you access the relationship as a property (after you update the profile) it will just then fetch the relationship:

```
$profileImage = $user->profile; // not null
```

The same should happen if you already have the relationship loaded:

```
$user = new User($userData);
$user->save();
$currentProfile = $user->profile; // null

$profile = new UserProfile($profileData);
$user->profile()->save($profile);

$user->refresh();

$currentProfile = $user->profile; // not null
```

From the docs:

> The save and saveMany methods will persist the given model instances, but will not add the newly persisted models to any in-memory relationships **that are already loaded** onto the parent model. If you plan on accessing the relationship after using the save or saveMany methods, you may wish to use the refresh method to reload the model and its relationships: (...)

Comment: Hi @Kenny Horna +1. When 1)I query a model/relationship and 2) then do a processing that takes considerable time for example (but does not modify the model/relationship) and 3) go back to work with that model/relationship, is it necessary to reload (because of the time the previous processing took, **which would lead to new information in the database**), or only when **there are actually modifications** in the data involved?

Comment: @Coder23 It depends on your use case and how your model is used across your app. But in my opinion, if the processing takes considerable time to finish then it'd be a good idea to reload the data before updating the model.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Doc's forgot to mention that the relationship must be previously loaded for that trick.

```php
$trick = $post->comments;
$post->comments()->save($comment);
$post->refresh();
```

The *save* method not load nothing. You could use *load* method after save.

```php
$user->profile()->save($profile);
$user->load('profile');
```